# LEAD over a Cursor variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, database-cursor

I am attempting to get the next record in the cursor, without moving it. i.e Something like the peek function. Here is some sql code that I have written so far:

```
DECLARE
    @Id     varchar(80),
    @Name   varchar(80),
    @NextId varchar(80)

BEGIN

    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id,name FROM dbo.My_TABLE
    WHERE name like '%joe%';

    OPEN @MyCursor 
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @Id, @Name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        print 'Id is :: ' + cast(@Id as varchar(80)) + ' : ' + @Name
        SELECT @NextId=id, LEAD (id,1) OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM @MyCursor;
        print 'The next record is :: ' + @NextId
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
        INTO @Id, @Name
    END;
```

However, I get an error stating that:

```
The variable '@MyCursor' is a cursor variable, but it is used in a place where a cursor variable is not valid.
```

When I issue the select statement, I might get some data like this back

```
----+------
ID    NAME
----+------
5   + Joes
6   + FakeJoe
7   + Joes
8   + Joes
9   + MikeJoes
```

for me, it is important to compare ID 5 and 6 to see if the name matches. If it does, like 7 and 8, I want to delete the latter record. If it does not, like 5 and 6, I want to leave the records alone

Comment: sounds like you could do DELETE dbo.My_TABLE WHERE dbo.My_TABLE.name like '%joe%' AND EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM dbo.My_TABLE M2 WHERE M2.name like '%joe%' AND M2.ID< dbo.My_TABLE.ID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursor variable doesn't belong in a `FROM`.  Just add a column to the query itself:

```
SELECT id, name,
       LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id
FROM dbo.My_TABLE
WHERE name like '%joe%';
```

Comment: the next id in the table might not be sequentially higher by one in the table. I will update my question so I can elaborate more on what I am attempting to do

Comment: in this given answer, I don't think it does need to be higher by exactly one to appear though.  ~The next_id that you get, will be the next id, not necessarily id + 1

Comment: @angryip . . . I don't see what that has to do with this answer.  This gets the next id that matches the `where` condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah, you are correct. I was under the impression that when you do a lead, and do not issue the query on the same cursor, that the results might not match up.